# vb.net adding file to existing project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

Sorry to bother you with the same problem. 
I use Visual Studio for my small project. I'm a newbie.

I created separate project(s) Dailycount form & LiquorCount form.

I'm trying to bring the forms from both the project (using copy and Add Existing Items in solution explorer) to a Combined Project.

But when I open the forms in Design View. I just get the Blank form. when I build the application only 1 form is generated and another one is still blank form.

Files copied are:

```
Dialycount.vb
Dialycount.Designer.vb
Dialycount.resx 

Liquorcount.vb
Liquorcount.Designer.vb
Liquorcount.resx
```

Trying to find the solution to this for the last 2 weeks and it's frustrating.

Comment: No need to copy the files manually. Visual Studio copies them for you when you use `Add Existing Item`. Just select the `.vb` file (_not_ `Designer.vb`) and VS should also import the other related files automatically (assuming they are in the same directory).

Comment: Shouldn't you be using build solution instead of build project?